# Maven: Install external JAR automatically

Tags: java, docker, maven, jar

My project has a dependency on `oracle` jar to connect to it's database. Since it's a external jar, I downloaded it from oracle website and installed it manually using

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

running `maven clean package` on local runs fine, since the `ojdbc.jar` has been installed.

However, now I am moving the `build` step to `Docker` image.

```
from alpine/git as clone
workdir /app
run git clone --single-branch -b master https://github.com/xxxxxxxx

from maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine
workdir /app
copy --from=0 /app/idot/idot-backend /app
run mvn clean install -T 1C -DskipTests

from openjdk:8-jre-alpine
workdir /app
copy --from=build /app/target/idot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
cmd ["java -jar idot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

This step fails obviously during `build` since the external jar is not present. So to remove the dependency, I edited the `pom.xml` to include

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-maven-repo</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

and below dependency remains as before

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and then I deploy the jar file using below command

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Durl=file:./libs/ -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repo
```

This creates a `libs` folder with `ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar` and other meta information. I check this folder in `github`

Now while trying to build the `docker` image it fails with the below error message.

...
...
.
.
.

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/liquibase/liquibase-parent/3.6.3/liquibase-parent-3.6.3.pom (31 kB at 39 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.oracle:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/modelmapper/modelmapper/2.3.2/modelmapper-2.3.2.pom
```

.
.
.

```
  Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/atteo/evo-inflector/1.2.2/evo-inflector-1.2.2.jar (13 kB at 138 B/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/modelmapper/modelmapper/2.3.2/modelmapper-2.3.2.jar
```

.
.
.

```
  Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar (2.4 MB at 12 kB/s)
    Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2/springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar (2.9 MB at 14 kB/s)
    Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.12/byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar (3.3 MB at 14 kB/s)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 07:13 min (Wall Clock)
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-17T11:19:56Z
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project idot: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.novartis:idot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1 in local-maven-repo (file:///app/libs) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
    The command '/bin/sh -c mvn clean install -T 1C -DskipTests' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: You need to copy the ojdbc jar in your mvn build path using COPY statement in Dockerfile.

Comment: why the above is failing, it works on local

Comment: It will work on local because you downloaded the file manually(which will essentially be the COPY step in Docker). The ojdbc jar was then made available to project through maven install:installfile. Also since you have local mvn repository setup, the jar will be available at: `${project.basedir}/libs`. But this your local and this would have worked if you had committed  `${project.basedir}/libs` as well, which I believe isn't the case.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of a repository, and that the Docker build does not have acces to the one you have put the jar in unless you explicitly tell it how.

Comment: @Saurabh as mentioned I have commited the `${project.basedir}/libs` folder also. It's showing the error message with the committed folder.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen since I committed the libs folder which was generated on using `mvn deploy` command so `Docker` should also see this folder

Comment: Again, make the jar available at correct path! This is evident from the stacktrace - maven is unable to find the jar at your specified path - (file:///app/libs) because of this statement- ``copy --from=0 /app/idot/idot-backend /app`` and your configuration in pom.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of all the headaches, I added the same install command in `docker` file also. It now works fine.

```
from alpine/git as clone
workdir /app
run git clone --single-branch -b master https://@github.com/xxxx

from maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine
workdir /app
copy --from=0 /app/idot/idot-backend /app
run mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/app/ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
run mvn clean install -T 1C -DskipTests

from openjdk:8-jre-alpine
workdir /app
copy --from=build /app/target/idot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app
cmd ["java -jar idot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used same approach, Its works for me. You can see here..

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
        
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-repository</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl="file:\\\<project-path>\repo" -Dfile=Java-WebSocket-1.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=org.java-websocket -DartifactId=Java-WebSocket -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.4.2-SNAPSHOT
```